# Get KeyStroke for "<" and ">"

Tags: java, swing

I would like to use keybinding for the `<` & `>` keys and then use this on my JFrame.

I am using the following code to try and get it for the < key.

```
KeyStroke testStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("<"); 
mainJFrame.getRootPane().getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW)
                        .put(testStroke, "clickButton");
mainJFrame.getRootPane().getActionMap().put("clickButton", new AbstractAction() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            System.out.println("PRESS!!!!");
        }
});
```

I am not able to get it to work. However it works good if i use a key like A

```
KeyStroke testStroke = KeyStroke.getKeyStroke("A");
```

So i think is the KeyStroke that is wrong and the rest of the code is OK.

**How do i get the keystroke for the the keys < & >?**

Comment: Do you mean arrow keys? Add a key listener.  In the keypressed event, look for KeyEvent.VK_LEFT and KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT.

Comment: I mean the less than or greater than keys.

Comment: What's your [keyboard layout](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Keyboard_layout)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28char%29) for `getKeyStroke(char)`:

> Returns a shared instance of a KeyStroke that represents a KEY_TYPED event for the specified character.

```
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('<');
KeyStroke.getKeyStroke('>');
```

Before, you were using a String. Looking and the docs for [`getKeyStroke(java.lang.String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/KeyStroke.html#getKeyStroke%28java.lang.String%29):

> Parses a string and returns a KeyStroke. The string must have the following syntax:

This method has a complicated syntax to follow. A single letter worked, but a special character doesn't follow the syntax. The `getKeyStroke(char)` is a lot simpler. You should use it instead.

Comment: Thank you. It works fine with '<' instead of "<". 
Guessing that "<" counts as a String and '<' as a Char or how would you explain this?